# How to get specific string in explode array?

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, array

I have a shortcode where I'm trying to get a specific string from the `$args` array below.

Query:

```
$args = array(
    //'post_type' => $posttype,
    'post_type' => explode( ', ', $posttype ),
);    
$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Conditional:

```
if ( $posttype == 'cpt_press' ) :
    the_content();
else : 
    the_excerpt();
endif;
```

Shortcode:

```
[myquery posttype='cpt_press']
```

In the conditional above, I'm able to retrieve all posts with post type `'cpt_press'` if **I don't use explode**. The reason I used explode is so I could do this:

```
[myquery posttype='cpt_press, cpt_two, cpt_three, cpt_etc']
```

Any help?

UPDATED CODE BLOCK

```
function myshortcode( $params, $content = null ) {
    global $post;
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'posttype'      => '',
        'meta_key'      => '',
        'priority'      => '',
        'meta_compare'  => '',
        'layout'        => 'rows',
        'cols'          => 1, 
        'tag'           => '',
        'count'         => 10, 
        'orderby'       => 'date',
        'order'         => 'DESC'
    ), $params ) );   
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => explode( ',', $posttype ),
     );    
    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );  
    ob_start();       
    ?><div class="row"><?php    
    // The Loop
    if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : while( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();    
        if ( $posttype == 'cpt_press' ) :
            the_content();   
        else :
            the_excerpt();
        endif;
    endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?></div><?php 
    return ob_get_clean(); 
}    
add_shortcode( 'myquery', 'myshortcode' );
```

Comment: Post the code in context please, such that it can seen as a whole and pasted into a dev stack if necessary. As it is, I can't really tell what you are doing.

Comment: @tai-sem, Did you mean how to tell if 'cpt_press' is in the exploded string? You could use `if ( in_array( 'cpt_press', $posttype ) )`.

Comment: @1fixdotio Thanks I've already tried in_array :(

Comment: @s_ha_dum It's a basic shortcode plugin. You really need all the code? I can edit the question, but I'm searching for: how to grab a string from explode array.

Comment: Have you `var_dump` the "$posttype" and make sure it is an array with "cpt_press" in it?

Comment: If the sum of your question is "how to grab a string from explode array" then I'll close this as off-topic being a pure PHP question.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Sorry, I just didn't want to post 100s of lines of code. I posted the important blocks. It's not just PHP, it's within a shortcode plugin and WP_Query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @1fixdotio Yep, it's a string(38) "cpt_press, cpt_two, cpt_three, cpt_etc"

Comment: @TaiSem, I think you forget to set the $posttype variable as an array, that's why `in_array` doesn't work. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here. One is that the `explode()` doesn't actually specify the correct split string, which is `', '`, WITH a space.

What is written in the sample:

```
'post_type' => explode( ',', $posttype ),
```

What is written in the example shortcode:

```
[myquery posttype='cpt_press, cpt_two, cpt_three, cpt_etc']
```

Note that there is a comma AND a space between each post type. I would use `preg_split()` instead to allow for some flexibility in the way this value could be written in the shortcode:

```
'post_type' => preg_split( '/\s*,\s*/', $posttype ),
```

This will allow any amount of white-space to be used on either side of each comma between the post types in the given list string.

The second problem I see is that the given code is testing the `$posttype` variable for equality to ''cpt_press'`, even though it could be a comma-separated list.

Instead, check for membership of `'cpt_press'` in the `$args['post_type']`,  array, which will set to the list of the post types given in the `posttype` shortcode argument:

```
in_array( 'cpt_press', $args['post_type'] )
```

The updated code would thus be:

```
function myshortcode( $params, $content = null ) {
    global $post;
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'posttype'      => '',
        'meta_key'      => '',
        'priority'      => '',
        'meta_compare'  => '',
        'layout'        => 'rows',
        'cols'          => 1, 
        'tag'           => '',
        'count'         => 10, 
        'orderby'       => 'date',
        'order'         => 'DESC'
    ), $params ) );   
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => preg_split( '/\s*,\s*/', $posttype ),
     );    
    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );  
    ob_start();       
    ?><div class="row"><?php    
    // The Loop
    if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : while( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();    
        if ( in_array( 'cpt_press', $args['post_type'] ) ) :              
            the_content();   
        else :
            the_excerpt();
        endif;
    endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?></div><?php 
    return ob_get_clean(); 
}    
add_shortcode( 'myquery', 'myshortcode' );
```